Changing the title and labels of the plot provided by draw in the gratia package
I would like to change the title of the plot and the labels on the x and y axes without modifying the variable names in the dataframe.
I am using the gratia package.
library(patchwork)
library(gratia)  

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),    
  x1 = rnorm(100),   
  x2 = rnorm(100)    
)

model <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = data)
smooth_plot <- draw(model, ci_col = "steelblue", smooth_col = "blue", grouped_by = TRUE) 
smooth_plot <- smooth_plot + plot_layout(nrow = 1, ncol = 2)

print(smooth_plot)


In this case, I would like 'x1' to be replaced with 'Number of people having a vegetarian diet', 's(x1)' to be replaced with 's(Number of people having a vegetarian diet)', 'x2' to be replaced with 'Iron levels in the blood', and 's(x2)' to be replaced with 's(Iron levels in the blood).
This is only an fictious example for a more complex model and work.

A simple option would be to draw the plots separately which allows to set the plot and axis title using labs() and combining them afterwards using e.g. patchwork::wrap_plots:
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gratia)
library(mgcv)

p1 <- draw(model,
  ci_col = "steelblue",
  smooth_col = "blue", grouped_by = TRUE,
  select = "s(x1)"
) +
  labs(
    x = "Number of people having a vegetarian diet",
    title = "s(Number of people having a vegetarian diet)"
  )

p2 <- draw(model,
  ci_col = "steelblue",
  smooth_col = "blue", grouped_by = TRUE,
  select = "s(x2)"
) +
  labs(
    x = "Iron levels in the blood",
    title = "s(Iron levels in the blood)"
  )

list(p1, p2) |>
  wrap_plots() +
  plot_layout(nrow = 1, ncol = 2)



This works for me:
library(patchwork)
library(gratia)  
library(mgcv)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),    
  x1 = rnorm(100),   
  x2 = rnorm(100)    
)

model <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = data)
smooth_plot <- draw(model, ci_col = "steelblue", smooth_col = "blue", grouped_by = TRUE) 
smooth_plot[[1]][["labels"]][["title"]] <- "plot 1"
smooth_plot[[2]][["labels"]][["title"]] <- "plot 2"
smooth_plot <- smooth_plot + plot_layout(nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
print (smooth_plot)

